# Capture the response from watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, parsing, watir, watir-webdriver

Is there a way to capture the entire response from a query submitted via a watir-webdriver object/request. For example if I took the sample code below, is there an element that will capture the entire page from the form submission so that I may parse it for errors?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo'
b.text_field(:id => 'entry_0').set 'your name'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').select 'Ruby'
b.select_list(:id => 'entry_1').selected? 'Ruby'
b.button(:name => 'submit').click
b.text.include? 'Thank you'
```

Answer (score 0):

The .html element will return the page's source.
`puts b.html` will return the source of the current page.